# Changing position of SVG image inside frames

Tags: html, svg

I am newbie with html and Im trying to change the position of "red arrow" to down right position. How can I do this? Im using this svg image https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b5/PES-Red-Arrow.svg

Here is the code ( a abbreviated the image svg code):

## first I just create picture frames where "red arrow" is put

```html
<svg xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"" width='600' height='450' >

data:image/svg+xml;utf8;
IMAGESVGCODEHERE
</svg>"
```

How do I have to change this code to get "red arrow" to down right position?
Thanks!

[image: current view]

Comment: do you have a codepen with the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [transform="translate(x,y)"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform) to move the arrow

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   
     width="600" height="450" viewBox="0 0 600 450" >  

<g transform="translate(150,0)">
<image xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b5/PES-Red-Arrow.svg" />
</g>
</svg>
```

By changing the coordinates of translate(x,y), you can move the arrow in any direction. You only need to make sure that it does not go beyond the boundaries of the SVG canvas.

I indicated the width and height of the SVG canvas as a percentage to make the application adaptive

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   
     width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 600 450" style="border:1px solid gray;" >  

<g transform="translate(350,250)">
<image xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b5/PES-Red-Arrow.svg" />
</g>
</svg>
```